Monte Carlo method for likelihoods ratio density estimation
I recently started reading Stephen Kay's Fundamentals of Statistical Signal Processing - Detection Theory (Volume II) and there is something I do not fully understand about likelihoods and hypothesis testing.
Let's suppose that we have a problem of distinguishing between two hypotheses $$\mathcal{H}_0 : x = w \\ \mathcal{H}_1 : x = v$$ where $w$ and $v$ are random variables with distinct distributions (they could even be different "in nature", e.g. one is Gaussian and the other one is Rayleigh). One possible test is to write the likelihoods ratio $$ \Lambda (x) = \frac{p(x;\mathcal{H}_1)}{p(x;\mathcal{H}_0)} $$ and to decide for one or the other hypothesis depending on whether $ \Lambda (x) > \gamma$ or not, being $ \gamma$ a certain threshold. For example in radar applications, one receives a stream of samples and performs the likelihood ratio test for each sample in order to determine whether the sample reflects the presence of a target or if it is just noise. One way to assess the quality of this detector is to derive the so-called ROC (Receiver Operator Characteristic) curve, which is basically a plot of the probability of false alarm ($P_{FA}$) vs probability of detection ($P_D$).
The $P_{FA}$ can be expressed in terms of the probability density function of $\Lambda$ (which is, I think, a random variable itself), cfr. e.g. formula (15.7) in Richards' Fundamentals of Radar Signal Processing: $$ P_{FA} = \int_\gamma^{+\infty} p_\Lambda(s) \, ds. $$
Assuming that both $p(x;\mathcal{H}_1)$ and $p(x;\mathcal{H}_0)$ have explicit formulas, I am interested in finding $p_\Lambda$ (approximatively) and I was thinking about using Monte Carlo: i.e. generate lots of $x$, plug them in to $\Lambda$ and draw an histogram. However I am confused about which distribution $x$ should have; $w$'s? $v$'s? Both? It seems like $x$ can be both (again in radar applications, samples can be either noise or noise + echo target, and one just plugs them in to the likelihoods ratio), but how is that encoded in a Monte Carlo simulation? Does this even make sense?
Thank you!

Everything you've said is correct:

$\Lambda$ is indeed a random variable. It has two pdfs depending on whether we are in case $H_0$ or $H_1$.

Since it has a complex distribution, we can sample from $x$ then compute $\Lambda(x)$ in order to get information about the distribution

In order for step 2. to be accurate, we need a large number of monte-carlo samples

The relationship between the ROC curve and the density of $\Lambda$ is correct, but there is a slight detail that we must not overlook. Depending on whether we consider the density under $H_0$ or $H_1$, we get the false positives and false negatives for a given threshold $t$.
$$
\begin{align}
P_{FN}(t) &= E( \Lambda < t ; H_1) \\
P_{FP}(t) &= E( \Lambda \geq t ; H_0)
\end{align}
$$
the ROC is the parametric curve defined by those values as t goes over all real values


